# Restore MySQL DB from its folder

Tags: mysql

Some time ago, I've built an webapp on top of [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) server. At that time, I didn't do any export/dump of my MySQL DB but I've did a copy of the WAMP folder. Does anyone have any ideas about how I can restore my DB from the 'mysql' folder of WAMP?

I have the *.frm files and lots of mysql-bin.* files

Do you have any advice for me?

Comment: if it is not possible to restore the data inserts, I'll be happy to recover at least the table structures.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming default data directory setup (no partitioning etc), you follow these steps:

```
1) Stop the mysql server
2) Make a backup of the current mysql/data directory
3) Copy all the files and folders from the mysql/data backup directory into the active data directory
4) Restart mysql
```

This should let you restore the database to the point-in-time of your backup copy. The mysql-bin files aren't necessary for a recovery, but ibdata* files are (assuming innodb tables). If myisam, you should have .MYI and MYD files for each tablespace as well as the .frm files.

Hope this helps

Comment: ty for your replay. Unfortunately it restore just one table. It is true that I have some views there too. If I try to see the content of the view files, i can read the those queries, but i can't 'read' the queries of the tables.

Comment: did you ensure all the permissions are correct for all the directories/files. Reading the binary log isn't going to help you if you have a file-snapshot of the directory.

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysql server without starting WAMP or XAMPP.
you have mysql folder in WAMP right.
so you can use Mysql database server without any issues.

**just open command shell. Go to mysql/bin folder. start mysql server and use it**

**D:\WAMP\mysql\bin> mysqld --console**

---

**To take backup of your db open another command shell**.

**D:\WAMP\mysql\bin> mysqldump -uroot -pxxxxx databasename >D:\mysqldumps\bkpfilename.sql**

then your database exported into bkpfilename.sql  in D:\mysqldumps

if you want to create database in another mysql server using dump file

Start the server and open mysql client

opening a client

**1) mysql\bin> mysql -uroot -pxxxx**

**2) mysql>create database databasename;**

**3) mysql>exit;**

4) mysql\bin> mysql -uroot -pxxxx databasename

or

if file name or folder name contains spaces

** mysql\bin> mysql -uroot -pxxxx databasename<"D:\mysqldumps\bkpfilename.sql"**

Comment: You didn't answer the question asked:
"I have the *.frm files and lots of mysql-bin.* files"
Derek Downey explicitly states he doesn't have a .sql file or access to the original system in order to make one.